# How can I get a request's timestamp in ServiceStack?

Tags: request, timestamp, servicestack

This may seem silly but I can't find the request timestamp in ServiceStack. I'm looking for the ServiceStack equivalent of

```
this.Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Timestamp
```

in ASP.NET MVC.

I looked at the request headers but there's nothing there that resembles this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an ASP.NET host you can just get it off the HttpContext singleton, i.e:

```
HttpContext.Current.Timestamp
```

Otherwise if you didn't want to use a singleton you could travel down the Request object graph, i.e:

```
var aspnetRequest = (HttpRequest)base.Request.OriginalRequest;
aspnetRequest.RequestContext.HttpContext.Timestamp
```

Comment: I can't find RequestContext in HttpWebRequest. According to the [official specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx), it's not there.

Comment: Was a typo, HttpWebRequest is for a client HTTP Request only, HttpRequest is for server-side HttpRequest: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx